# Problems with simplest Arduino program

Tags: arduino, atmega

Today I started what is supposed to become a great Arduino career, but I'm already stumped. I may be going crazy, but shouldn't this code blink the LED on the Mega 2560?

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

unsigned int count = 0; 

void loop() {
  if(count%2) digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  else digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  delay(1);
  count++;
}
```

I know this is not elegant for a blinking LED, but this is a stripped down example for something else, where I need a counter and modulo operations on it. The 'Blink' program works, but this here doesn't.

Comment: If you're serious about the word "career" in your post you will immediately ditch the abomination that is Arduino C++ and learn to program microcontrollers in C and/or assembler.  Take this from a guy with 10 EE hardware patents.   And get a mixed-signal  oscilloscope to see signals that occur faster than the persistence of vision and an LED will allow you to see.  `delay(1000)` will only get you so far, and you've reached that point today

Comment: @TomServo would you recommend any resources or devices to 'em for further learning? (personally I would recommend Practical Electronics for Inventors 3rd E by Scherz and Monk, as a good base in analog properties is a powerful tool for solving digital weirdness) I doubt anyone would recommend `delay()` for practical code, but it's conceptually very easy to understand. This leads it to exist in most intro examples, where it has an obvious effect and naturally leads into other topics where it fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delay()`'s argument is measured in milliseconds (not seconds), so you probably want `1000` rather than `1` to observe the blinking!

```c
  delay(1000);
```

[Official Documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/delay/)

Comment: Personal gripe: I hate full blown multi-line `if` statements that just change a little value in a subroutine call. Look at how much you had to read just to turn a light on and off.  Examine this: `digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, count & 1);`

Comment: Ideally it would compile down to the same, and lets hear it for the ternary operator (boos from the peanut gallery)! @zeus300 if this solved your question, please mark it as the Answer with the check to its left!

Comment: @aMike: Agreed, but as I said, it is a stripped down example where more complex things are going to happen, and there I need the if's.